# How can i set a localstorage of my Token when google Auth is done?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth, passport.js

I tried to add a localStorage of my token when the process is done so i can get it in my react component (`let tok = localStorage.getItem('jwtGoogleToken');`)

like this :

```
if (account.enable === true) {
    //send token
    try {
      jwt.sign(
        {
          account,
        },
        "fatboardauthentication",
        // config.secretKey,
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) {
            done(err);
          } else {
            localStorage.setItem("jwtGoogleToken", token); // this wont work
            done(null, token);
          }
          // localStorage.setItem("jwtGoogleToken", token); // this wont work too
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      done(err);
    }
  }
```

La ligne `localStorage.setItem("jwtGoogleToken", token);` inside the else will not work, and when i click on my email to connect, i have this screen below and it still like this, charging infinitely :
[image]
if i move the localstorage outside the else it doesn't work too, i can't see the token in the browser.

this is the complete code :

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      // options for google strategy
      clientID:config.oauth.google.clientID,
     clientSecret: config.oauth.google.clientSecret,
     callbackURL: config.oauth.google.redirect,
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      // passport callback function
      console.log("passport callback function fired:");
      if (profile !== null) {
        console.log("Contenu de profile :", profile);
        var email = profile.emails[0].value;
        var nom = profile.name.familyName;
        var prenom = profile.name.givenName;
        var googleId = profile.id;
        Account.findOne({ email: email }, async (err, account) => { 
          if (err) {
            console.log("ERRORS 1 ???? ", err);
            done(err);
          }
          if (account) {
            //exist
            if (err) {
              console.log("ERRORS 2 ???? ", err);
              done(err);
            } else {
              //get account
              console.log("currentAccount");
              //check if enable = true
              if (account.enable === true) {
                //send token
                try {
                  jwt.sign(
                    {
                      account,
                    },
                    config.secretKey,
                    (err, token) => {
                      if (err) {
                        done(err);
                      } else {
                        localStorage.setItem("jwtGoogleToken", token); 
                        done(null, token);
                      }
                      // localStorage.setItem("jwtGoogleToken", token);
                    }
                  );
                } catch (e) {
                  done(err);
                }
              } else {
                done(
                  "This account is disabled, please contact support for more information",
                  null
                );
              }
            }
          } else {
            //new account
            if (err) {
              done(err);
            }

            const accountA = new Account({
              email: email,
              nom: nom,
              prenom: prenom,
              acceptCGU: true,
              google: {
                id: googleId,
                email: email,
                name: nom + " " + prenom,
              },
            });
            //save data
            await accountA.save((err) => {
              if (err) {
                done(err);
              } else {
                console.log("newaccount");
                //send email
                var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                  service: "Gmail",
                  auth: {
                   user: config.supportemail,
                   pass: config.gmailPSW,
                  },
                });
                var mailOptions = {
                  to: email,
                  from: config.supportemail,
                  subject: "Bienvenue chez FATBOAR !",
                  text:
                    "Bienvenue chez FATBOAR ! \n \n Votre compte : " +
                    email +
                    " a bien été créé. \n \n Nos dernières offres exclusives n'attendent plus que vous sur notre site Fatboar.\n A bientôt ! \n \n L'équipe FATBOAR",
                };
                smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    res.status(400);
                    resultats = {
                      success: false,
                      message: "Error : " + err,
                      result: "",
                    };
                    res.json(resultats);
                  } else {
                    //send token
                    try {
                      jwt.sign(
                        {
                          accountA,
                        },
                       config.secretKey,
                        (err, token) => {
                          if (err) {
                            done(err);
                          } else {
                            done(null, token);
                          }
                        }
                      );
                    } catch (e) {
                      done(err);
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  )
);
```